# Compiling assembly code for aarch64

Tags: gcc, assembly, arm, arm64

I have generated an assembly file try.s with aarch64 instruction set.I want to compile this on an ARM8 (aarch64 processor) running ubuntu.
my native compiler is gcc(4.8) and i use the following command to compile

gcc -o try.o try.s

I am getting the following errors
***Error : ARM register expected -- mov x10,x0***

It seems like the aarch4 registers are not being recognized although i thought gcc 4.8 supported aarch64. Can someone tell me what am i missing or is there any special option i should include.Or suggest me a native compiler(not cross-compilers) for doing aarch64.I would also like to use gdb to debug this natively.

Comment: Did you try generating asm from a C file (with gcc -S) to compare with your syntax? (and actually completely compile to check that your compiler works, but if it is the one that comes with Ubuntu, it should)

Comment: so... when i cross compiled it on an x-86 system with g++-arch64-linux-gnu it compiles allright, which makes me think the syntax is correct.Also It throws an error saying ARM register expected when i use the 64 bit access(x0-x30) :( . yeah compiler came with ubuntu gcc 4.8.2

Comment: Which Ubuntu is that? I tried on a aarch64 machine on the gcc test farm that has Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS, and gcc is 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.

Comment: ubuntu 14.04 LTS ... On Cortex A57(aarch64)

Comment: It kinda looks like you have a 32-bit binutils there, for whatever odd reason. What does `as -v` say?

Comment: hmm... GNU assembler version 2.24 (arm-linux-gnueabihf) using BFD version (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.24

Comment: Yup, 32-bit assembler. Either you've got some messed up multiarch packages going on or you're unwittingly running a whole 32-bit userspace (I'd check what `uname -a` reports).

Comment: is there any other native toolchain that supports aarch64..? I cant seem to figure this one out :(

Comment: that makes sense....how do i get the 64 bit assembler.. uname -a returns Linux tegra-ubuntu 3.12.67-g3a5c467 aarch64 aarch64 GNU/Linux

Comment: `apt-get install binutils:arm64`

Comment: Hey Marc ... I am not able to locate binutils:arm64 package...!!! so running above(sudo apt-get install binutils:arm64) gives error as unable to locate binutils......    i can install binutils , but how do get the specific one for 64..? and thanks for all your help.

Comment: There is something wrong with your system... Random check: `dpkg --print-architecture`, `dpkg --print-foreign-architectures`.

Comment: print architecture returns armhf , print-foreign-arch returns nothing

Comment: Notlikethat guessed right, you installed a whole 32-bit userspace... You will have to reinstall the whole thing, picking the right version of Ubuntu this time.

Comment: or build a cross compiler/assembler which is fairy easy these days.  if you are on the arm itself then sure install the right toolchain.

Comment: Heh, I guessed this might be a Tegra - last I heard, nVidia still doesn't provide a 64-bit userspace (I guess they share the same image for both 32-bit and 64-bit boards and just change the kernel), although in that case I don't like to think what they've done to prevent `uname` reporting `armv7` as the 64-bit kernel should in compat mode... Anyway, I suppose you could try hacking in Canonical's PPAs to get access to AArch64 packages, but it might be simpler to just install a proper 64-bit distro instead of "linux4tegra".

Answer (score 1):

`gcc` is for a 32b targets. 'Xn' registers are not defined for a **aarch32** instruction set. That's what compiler tells you.

Right toolchain is `aarch64-elf-gcc`.

PS: that's a good idea to make asm file extention `.S` (capital s)